# OpenShift Passphrase Lost. What Options Do I Have?

Tags: openshift, passphrase

I've lost the passphrase to my OpenShift account. :-(

What options are open to me?

I believe that I may need to use rhc to recreate private and public keys etc.

Is that correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should contact OpenShift abou this issue: https://developers.openshift.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

In the end I recreated private and public keys...